# In Oracle SQL, what would code like this be used for?

Tags: sql, oracle

Just studying some code , and came across this line:

```
v_VLDT_TOKEN_VLU := v_onl_acctID || ‘|’ || p_onl_external_id || ‘|’ ||  p_validation_target
```

It's a "validation token value" , but why would you concatenate the pipe symbol? I understand this is for dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Pipe symbol is used as a delimiter/separator between the fields:

Assume,

```
v_onl_acctID = 123
p_onl_external_id  = abc
p_validation_target = xyz
```

then

```
v_VLDT_TOKEN_VLU := v_onl_acctID || ‘|’ || p_onl_external_id || ‘|’ ||  p_validation_target
```

will evaluate to

```
v_VLDT_TOKEN_VLU = 123|abc|xyz
```

It is just another character for delimiter purpose and can be replaced with any other delimiter too. For reference, if the `|` is replaced by `*`, say

```
v_VLDT_TOKEN_VLU := v_onl_acctID || ‘*’ || p_onl_external_id || ‘*’ ||  p_validation_target
```

then the expression's value would be `123*abc*xyz`

Note:  `||` is used for concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the pipe symbol is being used as a delimiter between the three fields.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually seen similar code, but it was used to generate a unix statement that piped (|) the output of one command to another.  If I remember correctly, they had a table with all of our database hosts, and oracle data directories.  They used code similar to this to shell over to the specific database host, get a directory of the datafiles and write the output to a logfile back on the parent server which they then read in to update disk usage for reporting.  This was years ago so I'm sure there is a better way to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Comment = answer apparently.

v_vldt_token_vlu looks like it's built up of three fields, with a pipe between each of them...I assume the pipe is built into the token_vlu field and then being compared to the same fields concatonated together here. Pipe was probably a developers preference. No real reference to dynamic SQL here